# Mysql Error When Changing Column INT to Double through phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, integer, double

Hi im getting this error when im changing column type INT to Double
[image: This is the error.]

Comment: what is your DDL query?

Comment: im using phpmyadmin im not doing this with query.

Comment: Quick suggestions:   1. Empty the table of any data. 2. Define the default value for the field as 0.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to delete "Length/Values" Value.

[image]